# Optimal ice cream cone filling process on a conveyor belt with arbitrary distributed cones

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I have an algorithmic question that arose from a real-life production problem.

**Setting.** Empty ice cream cones are randomly distributed across a moving conveyor belt. The batcher equipment has a hosepipe that can move above the belt within some limits (considerably smaller than the length of the belt). In order to fill an empty cone the hosepipe is placed right above the cone and locked on it for some time until the filling process is over. So this means that the cone must remain in the hosepipe reach area while the filling is in progress. After it's done the hosepipe can move on to another cone. Clearly, if the speed is not big enough and filling process takes some time the system would miss some of the cones if cones are many enough and inconveniently placed. So the problem is to fill as much cones as possible by scheduling the order of filling beforehand.

[image: ice cream cone filling process]

Formally we have as input:

- *U* — speed of the belt
- *V* — speed of the hosepipe
- *W* — width of the belt
- *L* — length of the belt
- *P* — length of the hosepipe reach area
- *T* — time of the filling process
- *cones* — array of coordinates of cones on the belt

An output is ideally the list of cones to fill successively that ensures the maximum number of filled cones. Or at least an estimation of the maximal number of cones that are possible to fill.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One thing that isn't clear about your approach: The true optimal results depend somewhat on whether or not you know ahead of time where every single cone is. In real life you do not, but your wording suggests you do. Which is it? An algorithm for the former would not be appropriate for control on a production line (for that you simply always fill the the nearest cone to the hose that has enough time to be filled still, and have the hose move towards the inlet side when it is idle, then you just either keep unfilled cones going back around on the belt or add dispensers to meet throughput).

Comment: @JasonC, it's the latter, when we know all the coordinates beforehand and have an opportunity to schedule the movement of the hose to achieve the maximum result after one run of the belt.

Comment: Well you could run a genetic algorithm with semi-randomized cone orders. You could brute force it and do a search through a tree of all possible cone orders (node is cone, children are cones within accessible distance). You may want to visualize it as a stationary belt with the hose travelling over it, then it becomes a  path finding algorithm with constraints on where the hose can travel based on time (its movement window moves over the "stationary" belt at a constant rate, you can use this to build a graph with edge costs). But I wonder if it will *really* improve over "fill nearest cone"...

Comment: Btw I realize my first comment was unclear, so just to be clear: "Former" = know all cones ahead of time. "Latter" = live production line, unknown cone positions. And when I said "for that" in parenthesis, the "that" was referring to "control on a production line", not to "an algorithm for the former". Sorry about confusion, it was a bit poorly worded.

Comment: JasonC, thanks! I wonder how much simpler the problem would get if we consider the belt to be one-dimensional

Comment: I think this is NP-hard, since it seems possible to encode an instance of (a problem that is a slight variation of) Euclidean TSP inside it: just place a cone at every vertex, set the belt speed U to some tiny positive number, and make P long enough that any sequence of n "edges" could be traced.  (Having nonzero belt speed means the time to get from u to v isn't the same as the time to get from v to u if they're in different horizontal positions, but the difference can be made arbitrarily small.)  Add a large number of densely packed cones at one end, too many for the filler to ...

Comment: @G It's exactly the same problem. You could reformulate the 2D case by projecting it into 1D, the only difference is the hose speed is variable between cones (when projected, depending on their 2D distance). So it doesn't really change anything. 3D is the same as well. Btw if the hosepipe is on two independent servos "speed" doesn't fully determine time, it'd be a function f(cone1,cone2) that is the time it takes to travel  (maybe e.g.   speed*max(dx,dy)), and ps that function makes 1d/2d/3d identical. But that doesn't simplify / complicate anything, it's just something to note.

Comment: ... get them all before some slip out of the window.  Now the total number of cones filled depends on the time taken to fill all the cones in the encoded TSP instance, so (since we know the fastest way to fill the dense grid of cones at the end is with alternate up and down sweeps) if we want to test whether there is a TSP of total length < k, we can compute the number of cones f(k) we need in that final block, and then test if we can get all of them.

Comment: OTOH if you make the (fairly reasonable) assumption that we will never move the feeder "backwards", the graph representing movements between cones becomes a DAG, and many optimisation problems (e.g. calculating the shortest *or longest* path) become very easy.  Maybe one of these will map to (at least some special cases of) your problem.

Comment: This seems interesting, so I put together a quick simulation. I think I have a reasonably good algorithm for the real-time case. I'll put the code on github but [here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-75x_KNIDh4). I found that slowing down the belt increases coverage greatly while maintaining throughput. Algorithm in video is simple: Fill closest cone that is fillable within hose head range, drift right when idle, and to make up for missed clusters prioritize "urgent" cones that have a narrow margin between travel/fill time and out-of-range time.

Comment: JasonC, that's fascinating! I stared at this for 5 min. This is a good way to empirically estimate the percentage of missed cones for the definite set of parameters. Basically, this is what I was looking for. It would be interesting to fiddle with the parameters for your simulation and see how the efficiency changes. Hope you make it public, I'm looking forward to it ;)

Comment: @JasonC: Nice video. For comparing algorithms, it would be great to have the code you used to generate the input sequence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Optimal cone-filling with a forward-only dispenser

Let's suppose the conveyor belt moves right-to-left.  Below I'll describe a way to formulate and solve the problem in a way that fills the **maximum possible** number of cones, under the assumption that the dispenser never moves to the left faster than the conveyor belt does.  For n cones, the basic algorithm has a very loose (see later) upper bound of O(n^3) time and O(n^2) space -- this should be feasible for up to 1000 cones or so.  If you have more cones than this, you can break them into blocks of at most this size and simply process each block one after the other.  There's also a way to relax the never-move-left-fast restriction somewhat, and thus potentially fill more cones, without the whole problem becoming exponential-time -- I'll describe this later.

Let's suppose that all cones have positive x co-ordinates, and that the hosepipe reach area, which initially extends from x = 0 leftwards to x = -P, moves rightwards over the cones, which themselves remain stationary.  So at time t, the hosepipe reach area will extend from x = U * t leftwards to x = U * t - P.  When describing the position of the dispenser, I'll always use the same (that is, absolute) co-ordinate system; we'll ensure that it remains a valid position (inside the hosepipe reach area) by ensuring that at any time t, its x location is between U * t - P and U * t.  Notice that a (time, cone ID) pair is enough to completely determine the positions of both the hosepipe reach area and the dispenser, if we interpret it to mean that the dispenser is directly over the given cone at the given time.  (Later this will help in simplifying the description of the system state.)  Finally, I'll call any motion of the dispenser that does not decrease its absolute x co-ord (this includes any backward motion, relative to its enclosure, that is lower in speed than U, and also no motion at all) a "forward" motion, and any that does a "backward" motion.

### Dynamic programming formulation

Sort the cones by increasing x position, breaking ties arbitrarily.  Let (x_i, y_i) be the position of the ith cone in this sorted order.

Let e(i) be the earliest time at which we could feasibly position the dispenser over cone i if it was the only cone we cared about, and the dispenser was already "waiting" at the correct vertical position (namely, y_i) at the rightmost end of the hosepipe reach area: this is simply x_i / U.

Let m(i, j) be the time needed to move the dispenser from cone i to cone j, assuming that it's possible to do so without having to wait for either one to "scroll into view": this can easily be calculated for any pair (i, j) from their co-ordinates and the speeds V and U (this remains true even if the dispenser can simultaneously move at arbitrary speeds V_x and V_y in the x and y directions).

Now we come to the function that is the key to efficient solution of this problem:

**Let f(i, j) be the earliest time at which we could finish filling cone i such that we have filled exactly j cones so far (including this one, so 1 <= j <= i), or infinity if this is not feasible.**  Let g(i, j) be a helper function that is defined the same way, except that we allow the last cone-filling step to push the dispenser too far to the left (you'll see why in a minute).  We can calculate g(i, j) and, more importantly, f(i, j) as follows:

```
g(i, j) = max(e(i), minimum of f(k, j-1) + m(k, i) over all k s.t. j <= k < i) + T
f(i, j) = IF U * g(i, j) - P <= x_i THEN g(i, j) ELSE infinity
```

What a mess!  Let's go part by part.

The `f(k, j-1) + m(k, i)` term is the smallest amount of time it takes to fill j-1 cones, ending with cone k, then move the dispenser to cone i.  The `max(e(i), ...)` around this ensures that, if the movement implied by the above term would cause the dispenser to move too far to the right (i.e., to some x-co-ord > U * t), it won't be taken.  Instead, we'll move the dispenser to (U * t, y_i) -- that is, to the correct y co-ord for cone i and as far right as possible -- then wait for cone i to scroll in (and thus appear directly below the dispenser) at time e(i).  Regardless of which of these actions we take, it then takes a further T time units to fill cone i.

(Technically, the above calculation assumes that, if it's possible to move the dispenser to (x_i, y_i) by some given time t, then it's also possible to move it to (U * t < x_i, y_i) by that same time at the latest.  But since our starting x location is <= U * t, the only way this could fail to hold is if the function describing the time needed to move between 2 given points violates the Triangle Inequality -- something which doesn't happen when the hosepipe moves relative to its enclosure at a constant speed V, or independently in 2 directions at constant speeds V_x and V_y, or indeed uses any non-crazy drive system.)

What about the left edge of the hosepipe reach area?  `U * g(i, j) - P` is the position of the left edge of the this area at the time g(i, j).  Since that time is the *earliest possible* time that we could have finished the task of filling j cones, the last of which is cone i, that expression gives the leftmost possible position that the left edge of the hosepipe reach area could be in when the task is completed.  So if that position is still to the left of x_i, it means we can feasibly fill cone i after those j-1 earlier cones -- but if it isn't, we know that trying to do so will force the dispenser too far left (this might happen while trying to move to cone i, or while filling it -- it doesn't matter).  So in the latter case we slam the time cost associated with task f(i, j) all the way to infinity, guaranteeing it won't be used as part of the solution to any larger subproblem.

### Time and space usage

Calculating any particular f(i, j) value takes O(n) time, so calculating all O(n^2) of these values takes O(n^3) time.  However in practice, we will hardly ever need to consider all possible values of k less than i in the above minimum.  In addition to ensuring that the sequence of movements implied by `f(i, j)` remains feasible, the `max(e(i), ...)` is also the key to a big practical speedup: as soon as we happen on a k that causes the e(i) term to "kick in" (become the larger of the two terms compared by `max()`), it will remain the best feasible option -- since any subsequent k that purports to allow a faster completion of the task necessarily involves pushing the dispenser too far to the right in the final step.  That means that we don't need to try any of those other k values: e(i) is indeed the real minimum.

If all we wanted to calculate was the minimum time needed to fill some given number of cones, we could actually do it in just O(n) space, by making use of the fact that when calculating f(i, j), we only ever access previous values of f() having second argument equal to j-1.  But since what we actually really want is **the sequence of actions corresponding to such a minimum time**, we will need to record a table of predecessors p[i][j], and this does require O(n^2) space.

### Pseudocode

```
Sort cone[1 .. n] by increasing x co-ord.
Compute e[i] for all 1 <= i <= n.
Set f[i][1] = e[i] + T for all 1 <= i <= n.
Set f[i][j] = infinity for all 1 <= i <= n, 2 <= j <= i.
maxCones = 0.
bestTime = infinity.

# Compute f(i, j) for all i, j.
For j from 2 up to n:
    For i from j up to n:
        g = infinity.             # Best time for f(i, j) so far.
        For k from j up to i-1:
            z = f[k][j-1] + m(k, i) + T.
            If z < g:
                p[i][j] = k.
                If z < e[i] + T:
                    g = e[i] + T.
                    Break out of innermost (k) loop.
                Else:
                    g = z.

        If U * g - P <= cone[i].x:
            f[i][j] = g.
            If maxCones < j or (maxCones == j and g < bestTime):
                maxCones = j.     # New record!
                bestI = i.
                bestTime = g.
        Else:
            f[i][j] = infinity.

# Trace back through p[][] to find the corresponding action sequence.
For j from maxCones down to 1:
    fill[j] = bestI.
    bestI = p[bestI][j].
```

After running this, `maxCones` will contain the maximum number of cones that can feasibly be filled, and if this is >= 1, then `fill[1]` through `fill[maxCones]` will contain a corresponding sequence of `maxCone` cone IDs (positions in the sorted sequence) to fill, and the total time needed will be in `bestTime`.

### Possible enhancements

The above algorithm only solves the problem optimally under the restriction that the dispenser never moves backwards "too fast".  This could be quite restrictive in practice: For example, a pattern of cones like the following

```
X X X X


 X X X X
```

will cause the dispenser make a long vertical move between *every* cone it fills (assuming it's able to fill all of them).  Filling several cones in the same row and only then moving to the other row would save a lot of time.

The difficulty in solving the problem optimally *without* the restriction above is that it starts looking very much like certain NP-hard problems, like the Euclidean TSP problem.  I don't have time to look for a formal reduction, but I'm confident that the unrestricted version of your problem is NP-hard, so the best we can hope to do with a polynomial-time algorithm is to look for good heuristics.  To that end:

The DP solution above basically finds, for each cone i, the best way to fill j cones in total, ending at cone i and using only other cones *to its left*.  We can solve a slightly more general problem by breaking the sorted sequence of cones into contiguous blocks of b cones, and then finding, for each cone i, the best way to fill j cones in total that ends at cone i and uses only the cones that are either (a) in an earlier block (these cones must be to the left of i) or (b) in the same block as i (these cones aren't, necessarily).  The only solutions overlooked by this approach are those that would require us to fill a cone in some block and afterwards fill a cone in an earlier block (this includes, in particular, all solutions where we fill a cone in some block, a cone in a different block, and then another cone in the first block again -- at least one of the two moves between blocks must be a move to a previous block).

Obviously, if we pick b = n then this will find the overall optimum (in a million years), but b doesn't need to be anywhere near this large to get an optimal solution.  Using a variation of [the O(n^2*2^n) DP algorithm for solving TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) to assist in computing within-block optimal paths, choosing b = 10, say, would be quite feasible.

One more suggestion is that instead of fixing the block size at exactly b, cones could first be more intelligently split into blocks of size *at most* b, that is, in such a way that the (unknown) optimal solution seldom needs to fill a cone in a previous block.  In fact, provided that it's possible to heuristically score breakpoint "quality" (e.g. by using the minimum distance between any pair of points in 2 blocks), calculating a blocking pattern that maximises the score can easily be done in O(bn) time, using a (different) DP!

Comment: Thanks a lot for such elaborate answer! I'm gonna need some time to go through it

Comment: Were you able to understand and/or implement it in the end?  Let me know if you have any questions.  Also: I can't believe they closed this fascinating question!  I've voted to reopen, for what it's worth...

Comment: I got the part with forward-only case, but I failed to understand the approach in which we break the sequence into contiguous blocks of b cones. How to find the best way here? Bruteforce? And also, suppose we can solve TSP with desired ratio precision/time, as this is an extensively researched area. How to apply it to our problem? TSP solution is useful when the number of cones is small enough so we can fill them all. But if not, we get something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MLWi.jpg).
I can't figure out yet how obtain the second solution using the first.

Comment: Here's a [simulation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cn1x7rynfdvmssp/IcecreamProblem.swf?dl=0) that I'm working on right now. SWF-file can be opened with flash player or browser.

Comment: Not quite brute-force -- O(n^2\*2^n) is more-than-exponentially better than the O(n!) brute force algorithm -- but still exponential unfortunately.  You would use DP to calculate, for each cone i and total number of filled cones j, the earliest time at which you could finish filling j cones using only cone-fill sequences obeying the following conditions: the last cone is i; any cones from block blockOf(i) appear at the end (formally: let p be the lowest index of any cone in the cone-fill sequence such that blockOf(p) = blockOf(i); then blockOf(q) = blockOf(i) for all q >= i).

Comment: In order to calculate this new kind of f[i][j], you would need to loop over all 1 <= m <= b (m decides how many cones from i's block to include at the end of the sequence), and for each value of m, loop over all cones k from earlier blocks (k determines which cone is the last non-blockOf(i)-block cone in the sequence), computing f[k][j-m] + cost(k, m, i) for each (m, k) pair and recording the minimum.  Here cost(k, m, i) is the minimum time required to (validly!) fill exactly m cones *in any order* in block blockOf(i), ending with cone i, if the dispenser is currently over cone k.

Comment: Regarding TSP: It's not obvious to me how to encode your problem as a TSP problem, although (if it's possible at all) it almost certainly will need to be an *asymmetric* TSP instance, since if U > 0 and cones a and b are at different horizontal positions, then moving from a to b takes different time than moving from b to a.  I can think of a way of encoding a TSP problem *as an instance your problem* -- that doesn't give you an algorithm for solving your problem, it only indicates that (unless I've overlooked something) your problem is at least as hard as TSP, i.e., NP-hard.

Comment: Sorry, the end of my 3rd-to-last comment should read " for all q >= p)."  Confusing!

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!